# Pass anchor name to ipyhon HTML display

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab

I have an HTML file that embeds element anchors so any browser can jump straight onto an element (e.g. `output_full.html#pp_var_2786448025406367408`).

I'd like to have Jupyter Lab render that HTML anchored element in a cell, but I couldn't manage to pass the anchor name (e.g. `#pp_var_2786448025406367408`) to ipython HTML display.

Is this even possible?

Comment: What way have you tried that has not worked?

Comment: I tried `from IPython.display import HTML HTML(filename="output_full.html#pp_var_2786448025406367408")` but it clearly fails because the anchor is not part of the file name. Anyway, the [HTML class](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.HTML) doesn't take any "anchor" parameter; may `metadata` param be it?

Comment: So, in general you want to extract a part of an HTML document and embed it? Well, that would require an HTML parser - the IPython display module is only for display. I can imagine one using `beautifulsoup` (like `soup.find(id="pp_var_2786448025406367408")`) or `html.parser.HTMLParser` for that, but don't think that there is an off-shelf solution.

Comment: Instead of extracting a part of an HTML, I'd like to point the renderer to the element anchor so that the visualization starts from there. Similar to what happens when you click on this sample link: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#decoupled-two-process-model